# Gradle project sync failed android studio version 2.2.3 ERROR

Tags: android

Well this is my first time using android studio and i keep getting an error message which says:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find method android() for arguments [build_43qncadg6ssgwl9025usbfvce$_run_closure3@c74f8ce] on root project 'MyApplication' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>                   Consult IDE log for more details
>   HERE IS THE CODE:
>   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

repositories {

 jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete)
 {

   delete rootProject.buildDir

}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

}

dependencies {

}
```

> ERROR: could not find method android() for arguments.

What does this error mean? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A typical Android project has a root project and a sub project containing the app. It seems you showed the `build.gradle` of the root project.

The `android` section would typically go into the sub project's `build.gradle`.